# Как сделать выпадающее меню на CSS

Tags: css3, html, css

Покажите, пожалуйста, как создать простейшее выпадающее меню, средствами CSS.

Comment: простейшее выпадающее меню делается средствами одного только html:

    <select> 
        <option value='1' selected='true'> some text </option>   
        <option value='2' > another text </option>   
    </select>

Comment: вы издеваетесь? сейчас сотни jQuery плагинов, позволяющие делать выпадающее меню. причем на практически всех сайтах этих плагинов есть примеры.

Comment: @Макс Жуков: Я не сторонник jQuery. Если возможно, я буду пытаться обойтись без JavaScript на странице вообще.

Comment: > Если возможно, я буду пытаться обойтись без JavaScript на странице вообще

ну а клиентскую логику как будете обрабатывать? Одними только формами с полной перезагрузкой страниц? В 2014 году это как-то архаично

Comment: @DreamChild: Там где требуется асинхронная передача данных JavaScript оправдан, в выпадающих меню можно обойтись и без JS. Страница будет грузиться быстрее. Клиентскую оптимизацию считаю наиболее важным аспектом разработки.

Comment: @DreamChild JS вообще и AJAX в частности хороши далеко не только возможностью асинхронного общения между клиентом и сервером

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/XGzmh/

```css
/*Обнуляем отступы*/
ul, li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;   
}
 
/*Задаём параметры блока, содержащего основное меню*/
#menu {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:50px;         
}
 
/*Задаём стили для разделов нашего меню*/
#menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
}
 
/*Стили для скрытого выпадающего меню*/
#menu > li > ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    display:none;   
}
 
/*Делаем скрытую часть видимой*/
#menu > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;  
}
```

```html
 <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Раздел1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Раздел2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Разде3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Подраздел7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>       
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu > li:hover > .sub-menu{display:block;}
.sub-menu{display:none;}
```

```html
<ul class="menu"><li><a href="url">Menu 1
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="url">sub menu 1</li>
    <li><a href="url">sub menu 2</li>
    <li><a href="url">sub menu 3</li>
  </ul></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Fuad Cavadov: Не работает! http://jsbin.com/jacosiwo/1/edit

Comment: @DezzaSimpson, если первый селектор заменить на такой: `.menu > li:hover > .sub-menu`, то всё заработает.