# Кнопка с селектом

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет,подскажите как реализовать такую кнопку с селектами[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

Comment: Более развернуто опишите, что вам нужно.

Comment: Как на картинке,кликаешь на кнопку и выпадает такое меню

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать выпадающее меню на CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/309040/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько понял основная мысль в показе скрытого меню по клику на кнопке.

```js
var linkBtn = document.querySelector('.show-menu');

linkBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 var menuList = document.querySelector('.menu--hide');

 if(menuList) {
  menuList.classList.toggle("menu--show");
 }
});
```

```css
.show-menu {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.show-menu:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu--hide {
  display: none;
}

.menu--show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="show-menu">Показать меню</a>

<ul class="menu  menu--hide">
  <li class="menu__item">пункт 1</li>
  <li class="menu__item">пункт 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Использовать готовые библиотеки, т.к. в них реализовано много нюансов. Рекомендовал бы этот вариант.
2. Использовать CSS.
3. Использовать JS, [например](https://jsfiddle.net/o4hkc1dz/). К сожалению, код на данном сайте сейчас не воспроизводится. Для воспроизведения перейдите по указанной ссылке выше.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#more").on("click", function() {
    $("ul").toggle();
  });

});
```

```css
button {
  border: 0;
}

ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="more" value="More..." />
<ul id="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```